# Who is a good Hazard Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am building a tournament grade triple and double battle team, and I need a good Hazard Pokemon. By that, I mean a Pokemon who can use Toxic Spikes, Stealth Rock, Sticky Web, or/and Spikes, with Stealth Rock and Sticky Web being necessary. Does even a Pokemon exist who can learn most of those?

Comment: Also, a side note: 'Setters' are also known as 'Spikers' or 'Hazards' (the moves they use being known as 'Entry Hazards')

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but I would point out that using a Pokemon that knows *all* of these moves is not a good idea, since there is no way a competent opponent will let you use all of them. Much more likely is you get one turn to use a hazard move, and then you'll have to either switch or use a damaging attack. Getting Stealth Rock up is feasible; getting SR + 3 layers of Spikes is not, let alone SR + 3 layers of Spikes + Sticky Web + Toxic Spikes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [Generation 5 moveset searcher](http://www.serebii.net/games/moveset-bw.shtml), I was able to search for a Pokemon that can learn *Toxic Spikes*, *Spikes* and *Stealth Rock*.

These are the Pokemon that came up:

- Omanyte
- Omastar
- Pineco
- Forretress
- Smeargle

Taking out regular Spikes, the list includes Nidoqueen & Nidoking,

Unfortunately a Generation 6 Moveset Searcher doesn't exist yet (that I have found), But so far, [Sticky Web](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sticky_Web_%28move%29#Learnset) is only known to be learned by:

- Spinarak (Level 50)
- Ariados (Level 58)
- Shuckle (Level 53)
- Surskit (Level 46)
- Sewaddle (Level 31)
- Galvantula (Level 65)

I know that [Shuckle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shuckle_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) can learn Stealth Rock as well, (although it's harder to get, requiring at least the Move Tutor in B2/W2). But that's the Pokemon you want that can learn the Stealth Rock/Sticky Web combo.

As for learning all the moves, only [Smeargle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Smeargle_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) is capable of getting all 4 of them through the move Sketch (which permanently copies moves).

So, to summarise:

- **[Shuckle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shuckle_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29)** can learn Sticky Web and Stealth Rock
- **[Smeargle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Smeargle_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29)** can sketch Sticky web and all the other moves, so it's the only Pokemon that can learn all 4 moves

Side note: Both these Pokemon have below-average stats, so it may be worth running with a different type of combo. [Forretress](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Forretress_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), which can learn the 3 Entry hazard moves listed above, would be a pretty good choice due to its High defensive stats and the fact that it is neutral or resistant to all but Fire types. Check out the current [Smogon Forretress analysis](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/completed-forretress.3492119/) for X/Y for ideas of movesets you could run.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your two moves noted as necessary ([Stealth Rock](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stealth_rock) and [Sticky Web](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sticky_Web)) Aren't very big on intersecting in Gen 6.

[Shuckle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shuckle_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) *can* know both moves, but he can *only* learn stealth rock through TMs in Gen 4, or through move tutoring in B2/W2. Which may leave you a little high and dry if you do not have the ability to transfer from 4th gen, or don't have B2/W2 (**note**: The Pokebank and the Gen5->Gen6 transfer tool are not even available yet). One thing to note about Shuckle is that while his defences are great, he leaves *a lot* to be desired in his other stats, if you go the Shuckle route, you'll probably want a +speed nature, max speed EVs (probably max out HP while you're at it), and a perfect speed IV for good measure. (See also; its [Smogon NU rank](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/shuckle))

So, if you do not have the ability (or the patience) to obtain a stealth rock Shuckle... [Smeargle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Smeargle) is your only other option to have those two moves (along with any other two moves you desire - I'd at least recommend Spore or something to keep him alive long enough to finish 'setting'). Starting at level 1 and every 10 levels thereafter, he learns [Sketch](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sketch_%28move%29) So just pair him up in a double battle with a pokemon who knows the move you want Smeargle to learn, and start sketching. Smeargle's [Smogon page](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/smeargle) might help you get an idea about how to build him (They rank him RU, which is still better than shuckle's NU).

Comment: Shuckle can make up for its low Health using Power Swap. This also helps screw around with sweepers, because it levels out both attack and sp attack for both pokemon. This can help keep shuckle alive long enough to set up.