# How would I teach Smeargle the specific moves I want him to learn?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-series

After asking this [***question***](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146753/who-is-a-good-setter-pokemon), I realized that I was going to use Smeargle due to the fact that he can learn all of the moves. But how? I know he gets Sketch, but it disappears after the use. How will I get him to be able to learn all of the needed moves?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enter Double Battles like the ones in [Restaurant Le Nah](http://www.serebii.net/xy/restaurants.shtml) (South Boulevard in Lumiose city) with Smeargle, and the Pokemon whose move you wish to copy.

Get that Pokemon to use the move, and then get Smeargle to 'Attack' your partner with Sketch.

I used this tactic to teach moves to my **['Catcher' Smeargle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145370/what-is-a-good-setup-for-a-catcher-pokemon-in-x-y/145371#145371)** variants.

**Notes:**

- Remember that Smeargle will learn Sketch every 10 levels (starting at level 1), and it can't know Sketch twice, so make sure you use the current Sketch before levelling up.
- The [Move Relearner](http://www.serebii.net/xy/movetutor.shtml) can also re-teach Sketch for the cost of a Heart Scale

Comment: Reminder: Smeargle learns *Sketch* every 10 levels so you can fill out his moveset or replace unwanted moves.

Comment: Okay, can he re-learn from move tutor, or must I level him?

Comment: @ShadowZorgon Pretty sure the move tutor can make him remember any move. Remembering moves probably doesn't work on Ditto, but only because Ditto never truly learns any moves; it merely transforms into another Pokémon that knows those.

Comment: I can confirm that Smeargle can 'relearn' Sketch.

Comment: @Nolonar - However I'm not sure if the Move Relearner can reteach any move, or just those learned naturally through level up i.e. I don't think I can reteach Smeargle 'Taunt' if I remove it

Answer (score -3):

Smeargle can learn ten moves because it learns sketch ten times or more times if it can relearn it from the move remember also use pokemon with pickup to get more hearts scales

Comment: Completely untrue. Technically he can learn as many moves exist in the game, but he is limited to 4 at a time, meaning you can have the Move Relearner help Smeargle remember Sketch at any given point in the game

Comment: @Slowpoke - well, not completely. He's right about Smeargle only learning Sketch 10 times. PokemonExpert - Yes he can be taught Sketch from the Move Relearner. Also, I found it easier to farm Heart Scales from Luvdiscs. You get something with Compound Eyes in the first slot (fainted), and then have something with Frisk and can learn Thief in the second slot (Phantump/Trevenant works nice). Then when fishing for Luvdisc, simply use Thief when Frisk tells you it's holding a Heart Scale.